# Why can't I import a React component from a file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I think I have written all the code right, but on the port I can only display app.js file

```
import React from 'react';

import ImgSlider from './ImgSlider';

import './App.css';

function App() {

return (

<div className="App" >
 
 <div className="book-box">
   <img src="" alt=""/>
   <div>
     <h1>Harry Potter</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
 );

 }

 export default App;
```

and I want to import div element from **ImgSlider**

```
import React from 'react';

function ImgSlider() {
 return (
    <div>
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
      <img src="" alt=""/>
    </div>
  );
 }

   export default ImgSlider;
```

When i open browser it only shows HARRY POTTER from the App.js, I think it should also display div from the ImgSlider
Console massage *Line 3:8:  'ImgSlider' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars*

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You arent rendering `ImgSlider`, just need to do this in App.js:

```
function App() {

return (

<div className="App" >
 
 <div className="book-box">
   <img src="" alt=""/>
   <div>
     <h1>Harry Potter</h1>
     /* ADD this code*/
     <ImgSlider />
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
 );

 }
```

This is just an example, you can add the `<ImgSlider/>` wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

To render some content from imported component you have to render it like:

```
return (
<div className="App" >
 <div className="book-box">
   <img src="" alt=""/>
   <div>
     <h1>Harry Potter</h1>
     {/*Place it where you want to show it */}
     <ImgSlider />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `<ImgSlider />` into App

Your final code would look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ImgSlider from './ImgSlider';
import './App.css';

function App() {
 return (

 <div className="App" >
 
  <div className="book-box">
    <img src="" alt=""/>
    <div>
      <h1>Harry Potter</h1>
      <ImgSlider />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```